# Error parsing XML file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse a simple XML file but I'm having trouble trying to obtain a value I need. The current error message I'm getting says node is not an object or is null. I'm testing on both I.E. 6, 7, FF 2,3

Here's the XML file:

```
<bookstore>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myTargetValue"/>
  </appSettings>
</bookstore>
```

Here's the script I'm trying to use:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else
    {
      xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    xhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xhttp.send("");
    xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
    alert(xmlDoc.xml)

    var xpath = "/bookstore/appSettings/add[@key='myKey']";
    var node  = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(xpath);
    alert(node.getAttribute("value"));    
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: your XPath returns: <add key="myKey" value="myTargetValue"/>
  Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise using a library such as jQuery to make your life easier - no more `document.getElementById()`-ing! In jQuery you can just do:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: processXml
});

function processXml(xml)
{
    xml = $(xml);
    var value = xml.find('bookstore appSettings add[key=myKey]').attr('value');
    alert(value);
}
```

**Edit:** I'm not that familiar with XPath, so I figured I would explain the `find()` call in case I misread what you're trying to select from the XML. jQuery uses CSS selector syntax. So, that `find()` will select `add` nodes that have the `key` attribute equal to `myKey`, which are descendant elements of `appSettings`, which descend from `bookstore` elements.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help... Matt, any ideas why it's not working on IE6?

Comment: Nevermind, I think it's getting blocked by my browser security, thanks again for the help.

Comment: I still suggest you try out jQuery - it removes all the nasty browser dependency (for the most part) like having to do object detection for the XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The method for evaluating your Xpath is not correct for firefox.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript For a good intro to using XPath in firefox.

Also see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath for XPath details

For your example, you would need

```
var node = xmlDoc.evaluate("/bookstore/appSettings/add[@key='myKey']", xmlDoc, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp for How to accomplish this in both IE and firefox

Comment: where do you need xmlDoc.evaluate?

Comment: *document*.evaluate() is for DOM3 XPath supporting browsers

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure your XML is returning correctly, can you please alter your code:

```
// ...
xhttp.send("");
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

alert(xmlDoc.xml)
```

I suspect you don't get your XML data back from your request.

Answer (score 0):

Before dealing with JavaScript, I would try to open the XML document directly in the browser typing the URL and see if it displays correctly.